# improve looping on large object array

Tags: javascript, json, performance

I have a large JSON file of 7MB ( 11000 objects ). Every object contain several items that look like this:

```
[  
   {  ...
      "startingTime":"Date1",
      "endingTime":"Date2"
      ...
   }
]
```

In my HTML I have slider that contains daily Hours:Minutes.

When user moves the slider I should update the DOM by filtering the data from the file in order to find:

> StartingTime <= SelectedTimeOnSlider <= EndingTime

Then use the filtered data to print SVG shapes on a map ( tubeMap + trains ). ( without forgetting to `remove()` precedent shapes from DOM before drawing new ones ).

The problem is that filtering all objects every time user slides the cursor makes the UI not fluid.

So I tried another approach:
Use a backend to generate a new JSON with this format

```
[  
   {  
      "00:00":{  
         "data":""
      },
      "00:01":{  
         "data":""
      },
      "00:02":{  
         "data":""
      }
   }
]
```

Then send the new JSON to the front. So when user selected a day time I don't filter any more all objects (it's done in the back-end) - I just select the the ObjectKey of `selectedTimeOnSlider` of the new format then add the data to the DOM.

But I have noticed that performing this calculations upstream is too long as well ( more than 25 second to perform from 00:00 to 02:00 ) => front-end keeps waiting for data too long.

So, I would ask if there is a way to increase the performances of filtering? or another approach ? ( indexing ? )

For informations the large JSON file is not static, it depends on day selected on a calendar.

**Update**
Here's the code that I use to filter data

```
let formatTrips = function (data:any) {
    var arr = [], i, j;
    for(i=0; i<24; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<60; j++) {
            arr.push((i<=9 ? "0"+i : i )+ ":" + (j<=9 ? "0"+j : j) );
        }
    }
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var arrFormated = arr.map(time=> {
        let schedulesFiltered=[];
        let nowFormat = moment(time, 'HH:mm');
         schedulesFiltered= data.filter(elm => {
        let before = moment(elm.tp_org_r, 'HH:mm:ss'); //tp_org_r = startingTime
        let after = moment(elm.tp_des_r, 'HH:mm:ss');//tp_des_r = endingTime

        let checkifBetween = nowFormat.isBetween(before, after);

        if (checkifBetween) {
            return elm;
        }
        });
        //console.log(schedulesFiltered)
        return schedulesFiltered

    })
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    console.log('Execution time: ' + time);

}
```

Additionnal informations :

- the http request took 9 seconds to get the file but this is not the problem.I'm focusing on the time filter that took to much. 24*60 loop on array of 11000+ object item.
- In my first approach ,I'm loading only one time the json file and save it on a store ( ngrx angular store ) then filter every slide value change.

Comment: Have you measured the performance? (1) How long does it take to filter? (2) How long does it take to rerender? (3) 25 seconds is way too long, you are doing something wrong there. Could you show that code?

Comment: Are you making an HTTP request for the JSON data every time the user changes the slider? Or do you do it once on page load as a JS variable?

Comment: Add your code for filtering, it's unclear if i'ts sorted in some way?

Comment: You realize that you filter the data *120* times ...

Comment: for 2 hours it's 120 time yes, but I should do it for 24 hour so 1440 time ( in my second approach..) But in my first approach it's one time every slider change, but if user slide quickly the slider, UI get not fluid

Comment: If you set a timeout of 200ms on slider change before filtering UI will not clog, giving time for user to slide smoothly and when he stops, then show the filtered records for given time

Comment: And you can [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the result of that filtering for each time but only after the user requests it. Until then you're wasting precious CPU cycles

Comment: @JonasWilms in my first approach filtering on selected daytime took less than one second but when user slide quickly the slider slides not with a fluid way.

Comment: @BrettGregson I have updated my post you have the answer.

Comment: @CarlosSá json file is not sorted so I should run through all of it. And yes I could set a timeout to smooth the slider browsing ( I'll do that if no other solution ), but What I prefer to do is to update dom when user is holding mouse on slider

Comment: Do start and enddates overlap? I.e. is there 0:00 - 1:30 and 0:30 - 2:00 ?

Comment: @JonasWilms as in my code it's every one minutes

Comment: @infodev I mean the dataset ... Do two elm s overlap? If not, then the filtering can be done way faster.

Comment: Yes it overlaps , concretely it's a subway system so many trains runs at the same time

Comment: Ah okay, so in other words: When you slide, the trains move?

Comment: yes the goal is to show trains moving on a map, if not update trains position on mouseup

Comment: Okay, this changes everything, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the goal is to show trains moving on a map

And thats were we should start:

Group the times *by train*. This can be done in O(n), and it won't increase the datasrts size (so this could be done on the backend too, see below for considerations).

Now why does that help? This reduces the datasets size we have to filter a lot. The 11000 events probably only refer to a few hundred trains.

Then initially, generate the following:

- A Map (train id - train) of the trains currently shown
- A sorted array of trains by departure time
- A sorted array of trains by arrival time.
- The position of the last train departed at the current slider position
- The position of the last train arrived at the current slider position

Now whenever the slider moves, all you have to do is:

- Move the departure position on the array of departures, for every train you step over add the train to the Map and to the DOM.
- Move the arrival position on the array of arrivals, for every train you step over remove the train from the Map and the DOM.

(If the slider moves backwards, the procedure is the opposite).

Then for every train currently shown, *adjust the position if necessary*.

This will be a lot faster, I'd imagine that for a typical slider step, ~20 trains move, ~1 departs, ~1 arrives, so you have to do *22 updates*, instead of *11000*.

---

*Various other optimization tips I wrote while the question was evolving, they might still be helpful, although irrelevant if the upper tip was applied*

The code that you are using to group on the backend is really unoptimized as it `.filter`s the `data` array 120 times. Here is how you could do that while iterating just once over the dataset, then for every entry go over all minutes it belongs to and add it there:

```
   const toMinutes = date => {
     const [hours, mins] = date.split(":");
     return (+hours * 60 + +mins);
   };
   const fromMinutes = minutes => {
     const mins = minutes % 60;
     const hours = (minutes - mins) / 60;
     return hours + ":" + mins;
   };

   const START = "tp_org_r", END = "tp_des_r";
   const groupByDate = { /* "01:20": [...] */ };

   for(const elm of data) {
     const start = toMinutes(elm[START]);
     const end = toMinutes(elm[END]);
     for(let minutes = start; minutes <= end; minutes++) {
        const id = fromMinutes(minutes);
        if(!groupByDate[id]) groupByDate[id] = [];
        groupByDate[id].push(elm);
     }
 }
```

But this approach has one big flaw: it massively *duplicates items*. I would never do this on the backend, because this will really increase the filesize sent to the frontend, and thus you will loose the slight performance benefit you might gained through the increased time it takes to send the data to the frontend. Also as it seems there is no way to cache it on the backend, so for every single client you have to redo the calculations. In other words: You are wasting *your computation time* (you pay the server, the client is "free") and you don't gain any benefit from it (calculations on the server make sense if you (1) reduce the amount of data sent to the client, thus decreasing page load time and/or (2) calculate the data once, then serve it to hundreds of clients).

You could do that on the frontend, but I don't think that building up this lookuptable is actually worth it (as filtering the date is actually quite easy).

Instead, send all elements to the frontend, then filter there. If the dataset is ordered, filtering is straightforward, and you don't even have to iterate over all 11000 elements:

1) Sort the array by starttime.

2) Find the first position were the starttime is smaller than the slider time minus the maximum duration (I assume this is just a few minutes). Do the same for the last position were the endtime is bigger than the slider time plus the maximum duration. Through that, we eliminate *a lot* of those 11000, the resulting range can then be easily filtered.

The benefit might not be clear yet, *but if the slider moves*, all we have to do is to *move* the start and endposition too. In other words, we don't have to look at all 11000 elements again, we just move the range slightly to the right / left, the  we filter this *tiny* range.

> But in my first approach it's one time every slider change, but if user slide quickly the slider, UI get not fluid

Thats quite easy to fix. If the user slides quickly, *he does not want and need to see the events he is sliding over*. Do the following:

(1) When the user starts sliding, hide the current elements and show some kind of loading indicator.

(2) When the user stops sliding, wait a short time, then generate the filtered results.

Through that, the page only rerenders *twice*, which will drastically reduce the amount of calculations done, and the UI is way more fluent (as the update happens when no user interaction is done, thus even if the calculation is heavy, the user won't notice it as there is no *lag*).

Comment: So doing filtering on front end is faster then backend ? Actually dataset is not filtered. btw I'm not using seconds

Comment: Maybe if instead of saving the full data you save a reference to it? e.g. You save all the data in a map and store their keys in your `groupByDate` object

Comment: Can you edit your code please as i'm using only hours:minutes and add some comments because I'm not understanding exactly what you are doing. Thanks

Comment: @infodev no, assuming that you are visiting the page in chrome and your backend runs on NodeJS, no matter wether you calculate it on the front or backend, it will roughly take the same time as there is the same JS engine running under the hood. *But* loading time is a performance feature too. If the "optimized" datastructure is lets say 14mb big, the client will spend twice the time on loading / parsing the data.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I'll try to use your one iteration algorithm and see how performances are

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation ! A last thing that I would ask you for in the groupbyDate algorithm , is that the id objectKeys are not sorted neither in HH:mm format and for 24h not 2, Can you edit it so that it condiders these  conditions ? I think in a next level I'll update my program with your last update proposition.

Comment: Object keys aren't really sorted. I don't see why you want to sort it, but if you want to, turn the object into an array, then sort that.

Answer (score 1):

> For better performance you should know the big problem is rendering and not
>   filtering.

Your problem come from using `Date` object and comparison dates. for better performance you can convert your data first from `Date` type to `Number` type (as milliseconds) and then compare numbers with each others. I changed your code and you can see the sample.

And You should know that loops performance in javascript is different with each other:

I compared the summing of random 10k items using for, for-of, while, forEach, and reduce. Running the tests 10,000 times returned the following results:

```
For Loop, average loop time: ~10 microseconds
For-Of, average loop time: ~110 microseconds
ForEach, average loop time: ~77 microseconds
While, average loop time: ~11 microseconds
Reduce, average loop time: ~113 microseconds
```

and you can use `Object.keys` and `Object.values` and `Array.map` and `Array.filter` in the proper way if you needed.

```js
let formatTrips = function (data) {
    var arr = [], i, j;
    for(i=0; i<24; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<60; j++) {
            arr.push(i*60*60*1000 + j*60*1000 );
        }
    }

    var start = new Date().getTime();
    const dataWithTimeStamp = data.map((d) => (
      {
        ...d,
        tp_org_r: (new Date(d.startingTime)).valueOf() % (24*60*60*1000), // just get time in miliseconds
        tp_des_r: (new Date(d.endingTime)).valueOf() % (24*60*60*1000) // just get time in miliseconds
      }
    ));

    var arrFormated = arr.map((time)=> {
        let schedulesFiltered=[];
        schedulesFiltered = dataWithTimeStamp.filter(elm => (elm.tp_org_r <= time && elm.tp_des_r >= time));
        //console.log(schedulesFiltered)
        return schedulesFiltered

    });
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
}

// Create sample data
const sampleData = [];
const date2019ToMiliseconds = (new Date("2019-01-01")).valueOf();
const miliSecondsFrom2019 = (new Date()).valueOf() - date2019ToMiliseconds;
for(let i = 0;i<10000; i++){
  const randomDate = new Date(Math.floor(date2019ToMiliseconds+Math.random()*miliSecondsFrom2019)).valueOf(); // Random Date between 2019-01-01 till now
   sampleData.push({
      "startingTime": randomDate,
      "endingTime":randomDate + (1000*60)
   })
}
formatTrips(sampleData);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go back to the original structure, and pre-calculate the same helping structure on the client side.
To even optimize it further you could maybe lazily update the "cache" structure by anticipating the user's actions (and if the cache was not filled yet, block the ui until you do).

Comment: thanks , do you think that pre-calculate on front end is faster than back end ?